# Duplicate Validation Errors in Struts2

Tags: java, struts2

I am using validate() in my Action and here is how my validate() method looks.

```
public void validate() {

    logger.info(".validate() : userName=["+userName+"] & password=["+password+"]");

    clearActionErrors();

    if(userName==null || userName.length()==0){
        addFieldError( "userName", "User Name is required." );
    }

    if(password==null || password.length()==0){
        addFieldError( "password", "Password is required." );
    }
}
```

And in the jsp i added  in the  section.

The errors are showing up as expected. How ever when i refresh the page i see errors twice. Also if i keep refreshing it the no.of times the error message gets displayed is incremented by 1.

Not sure what's wrong with this.

I tried even calling clearActionErrors(); in my execute() method and that doesn't seem to resolve the Issue.

thanks

Comment: additionaly need code from your jsp and struts config file

Comment: are you using spring plugin for creating action instances???

Comment: I'm with Umesh; this is almost always due to using Spring and creating singletons rather than prototype beans.

Comment: are you using ajax to send the validation request?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a table on ur jsp to display the form, then make sure that the table is a parent of the form tag. If the table is a child of form tag, the validation messages wont get cleared each time. Making the form tag as a child of table tag would solve your problem.